# Using RadioButtons to query a database

Tags: python, flask, radio-button, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask web applications to query a database (SQLite) and have the results show up in a Jinja2 template so it can be seen on a site. Python is used throughout.

The general idea is that the user will select 3 different parameters, using Radio Buttons, and will be given a result based on those parameters.

I changed it a little to try and make sense for people. A user would go on the site, and would answer the 3 questions:

**How is your mood?
How long do you have to eat?
What is your diet for the meal?**

And using those answers, the site would display a good time to eat, the best food and the best drink for breakfast. The database would have all the different food options. They are paired in a way that the columns cannot be mixed, one row (or id) should be called at a time.

Database format is as follows:

```
class Breakfast(db.Model):
    __tablename__= ‘breakfast_preferences’
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    breakfast_time = db.Column(db.String)
    breakfast_food = db.Column(db.String)
    breakfast_drink = db.Column(db.String)
    breakfast_mood = db.Column(db.String)
    breakfast_duration_available = db.Column(db.String)
    breakfast_diet = db.Column(db.String)
```

The Form is as follows:

```
class GeneratorForm(FlaskForm):
    mood = RadioField("Moods", validators=[InputRequired()], choices=[('happy', 'Happy'), ('sad', 'Sad'), ('okay', 'Okay'), ('angry', 'Angry')])
    duration_available = RadioField("Duration", validators=[InputRequired()], choices=[('five mins', 'Five Mins'), ('ten mins', 'Ten Mins'), ('30 mins', '30 Mins'), ('an hour', 'An Hour'), ('1 hour +', '1 Hour +')])
    diet = RadioField("Diet", validators=[InputRequired()], choices=[('vegan', 'Vegan'), ('vegetarian', 'Vegetarian'), ('none', 'None')])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

This is where it gets messy. I figured out how to get a singular result to print into the jinja2 templates, but it had to be done manually by typing it in. I would like it to be possible to query the database by filling out the radio buttons in the flask form, and then the route to the next page /results.html, the homepage being /index.html or ‘/’.

The app routes are as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", template_form=GeneratorForm())

# results page
@app.route('/results/<mood>/<duration_available>/<diet>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    form = GeneratorForm(request.form)
    mood = Breakfast.query.filter_by(breakfast_mood=“happy”, breakfast_duration_available=“five mins”, breakfast_diet=“none”).first()
    duration_available = Breakfast.query.filter_by(breakfast_mood=“happy”, breakfast_duration_available=“five mins”, breakfast_diet=“none”).first()
    diet = Breakfast.query.filter_by(breakfast_mood=“happy”, breakfast_duration_available=“five mins”, breakfast_diet=“none”).first()
    time = Breakfast.query.filter_by(breakfast_mood=“happy”, breakfast_duration_available=“five mins”, breakfast_diet=“none”).first()
    food = Breakfast.query.filter_by(breakfast_mood=“happy”, breakfast_duration_available=“five mins”, breakfast_diet=“none”).first()
    drink = Breakfast.query.filter_by(breakfast_mood=“happy”, breakfast_duration_available=“five mins”, breakfast_diet=“none”).first()
    return render_template('results.html', mood=mood, duration_available=duration_available, diet=diet, time=time, food=food, drink=drink)
```

How do I have the results page be separate from the index, and take the query from the flask form?

There are absolutely glaring issues with the code, but that is also because I have been playing about with this for days. I just need advice on connecting all these parts.

Thank you for any help! This is long and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():

    form = YourForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Not really sure how is the structure for query your form properly

        var = Something.query.filter_by(....)

        return render_template('results.html', var=var)
    return render_template("index.html", template_form=GeneratorForm())

# I guess you display the form in index and the user get the results in results.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! How do the choices made in the radio button go into the query is basically my question here... its definitely Breakfast.query.filter_by() but for in the parathesis, I want the choices from the radio buttons to go in there. how would that work?